# Pointer to an array in Objective-C function call

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I want to pass an array of long long to an objective c function. I would like the array to be passed as a pointer, if possible, so that copying is not done. I wrote this code:

```
+ (int) getIndexOfLongLongValue: (long long) value inArray: (long long []) array size: (int) count
{
    for (int i =0; i < count; i++)
    {
       if (array[i] == value)
           return i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

to which I pass

```
long long varname[count];
```

as the second argument. I am wondering if I can pass this array as a pointer or if this method is fine. I don't need pointers to long longs but pointers to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* being passed in as a pointer (language pedantry notwithstanding); nothing's getting copied. `type[]` is, for the most part, the same thing as `type*`.

To confirm this, check out `sizeof(array)` in the method. You'll see it's the same size as `sizeof(void*)`.

If you really want a pointer to the array, i.e. a pointer to a pointer to the long longs, you'll need to use something like `type**`; but the only reason to want to do this is if you want to modify the underlying array pointer from the method, which is hardly ever the case.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand fully. Lets say I have an array of 1000 items (as an example) and I pass it into this function. Does the memory used increase only by the size of one pointer - 4-8 bytes?

Comment: (long long *)array  is the same as (long long []) array?

Comment: The array lives on the heap (usually). When you call the function, all you pass in is a pointer --- the location of the array. (It's actually quite hard to pass an array by value in C/C++/Objective C; you won't do it by accident.) Both `long long*` and `long long[]`, when used as parameter types, represent pointers.

Answer (score 2):

C arrays always *decay* to pointers when passed to a function or a method, so it is not copied in your example. A pointer to `long long` is automatically a pointer to an array of `long long`, by virtue of the operator `[]` being applicable to all pointers. Since your method does not modify the array, you may want to add `const` to highlight this fact in your API; other than that, your method is fine.

Comment: Could you expand on what "decaying" means here. Decaying from what? What does an array define what a pointer doesn't?

Comment: I think he means here by decay that the type becomes just a pointer whereas before is was a pointer that was called an array.

Comment: @MichelMüller See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/335858) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is just an extremely thin wrapper around regular C, so this is handled the same as it would be handled in C: passing by reference.

```
+ (int)getIndexOfLongLongValue:(long long)value inArray:(long long *)array size:(int)count
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == value)
            return i + 1;
    }
}
```

Then in the code that calls the function:
`int myIndex = [object getIndexOfLongLongValue: aValue inArray: varname size: count];`